# Global Exception Handler Not Called

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I'm attempting to create an oWin middleware class that will capture all exceptions in the stack, and handle them appropriately. A

Following [this](https://www.jayway.com/2016/01/08/improving-error-handling-asp-net-web-api-2-1-owin/) article, I created an `IExceptionHandler` class to pass the exception from WebApi up into the Middleware stack.

However, this does not appear to be working. Although the `HandleCore` method is called, and `info.Throw()` is hit, the exception never appears inside the Middleware class.

**ExceptionHandler**

```
public class WebApiExceptionPassthroughHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public override Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HandleCore(context);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        HandleCore(context);
    }

    private void HandleCore(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        //Pass webAPI Exceptions up the stack to the Logging Middleware - which will handle all exceptions.
        if (!ShouldHandle(context)) return;

        var info = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(context.Exception);
        info.Throw();
    }

    public override bool ShouldHandle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        return context.ExceptionContext.CatchBlock.IsTopLevel;
    }
}
```

**Startup**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use<LoggingMiddleware>();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        app.UseWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }
}
```

**LoggingMiddleware**

```
public class LoggingMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public LoggingMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {


        //TODO: Initialise the log
        try
        {
            await Next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            //This is not getting reached.
            var i = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside webapi.config, I have this command:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new WebApiExceptionPassthroughHandler());
```

How do I get the webApi exception to bubble up to the Middleware logging class?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to move to Owin get rid of that bad `System.Web`, and `GlobalConfiguration`. Try creating you Api config in `Startup`.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use<LoggingMiddleware>();


        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        //Move your WebApiConfig.Register here
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new WebApiExceptionPassthroughHandler())

        //Finally use your newly created config here
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.